# Supply multiple colorscales to PlotlyJs heatmap

Tags: d3.js, graph, plotly

I think I'm trying to do something that just is not possible, but I'm asking to confirm. I have a heatmap that I provide a custom colorscale for. However I have a need to supply a different (or multiple different) color scales for certain portions of the heatmap. Below is a picture explaining why.

[image]

In plot A, we have thresholds of -115 and -105. In a normal use-case these would be most of the range, but for this example, we have another set of thresholds much higher than that which spans most of the range. If the blue line crosses the yellow line, it should be colored yellow in Plot B and our colorscale approaches red the closer it gets to the red line.

In Plot B, we show where the blue line crosses our thresholds. The colorscale I'm providing the chart is for the set of lower thresholds. However the blue line never crosses the higher thresholds and is being colored incorrectly. So I think I would need to provide another colorscale for this portion of the graph. However, I don't think that is possible with Plotly at the moment. I'm looking for suggestions or ideas on what to do.

Comment: By defining the right color stops for a gradient, it should be achievable in d3. https://www.d3-graph-gallery.com/graph/line_color_gradient_svg.html

Comment: Would that example apply well to a heatmap as well?

Comment: For the heatmap, I would compute if a value is more than another and then render the rectangle with the appropriate color accordingly. Applying a gradient to a heatmap would be needlessly complicated IMO.

Comment: Also, not sure about plotly, but this is definitely doable in d3.js

Comment: I fear that calculating each rectangle for the heatmap would get rather expensive. In a more realistic application, I'd have roughly 12,000 blocks that all update once per second. That's why I was approaching this from a library-method rather than a brute force calculation.